# How to set specific color to JavaFX XYChart.Series?

Tags: javafx-2

I am trying to style my JavaFX linechart, but can't find any way to set color to specific series. I know, that I can style via CSS, but I can't find how to set ID or CLASS to my series.

Can anyone give me a clue on:

1. How to set a color to linecharts?
2. How to set a css class to series?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general the way preferred way to style charts is without code, using only css stylesheets as jschoen recommends.  Additionally, if further customization is required, you can use css lookups from code to dig into the the nodes generated from series data and apply various additional css styling.

Here is information about dynamically changing a [JavaFX line chart style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757848/how-to-dynamically-change-line-style-in-javafx-2-0-line-chart) and a [sample program](https://gist.github.com/2129306) to go with the answer. In the sample app, all of the additional css styling is done via a setStyle call from code.  Using a similar lookup technique, you could get access to the series nodes to apply an appropriate stylesheet styleclass rather than a setStyle call.

Comment: Just wanted to say you have some pretty nice sample programs on you git account. I ran across them earlier today, and lost a couple hours just looking through them. A very helpful resource. Thanks.

Comment: I can believe that CSS-based chart styling works well for 'dashboard' software, but it's an abomination for anyone trying to work with the data interactively.  Even javascript charting libraries typically don't force you to update a style sheet to change the point size on a single scatterplot.

Comment: I was styling my charts through code, but this haunted me since upgrading to JavaFX 17. The `setStroke` that I was changing is now immediately overridden by a css update. Other properties like strokeWidth still stick. Styling through code was more convenient for me, especially because API for converting color values doesn't even seem to exist.
Ultimately I would now advise to go the css route. See answer with the `lookup`.

Comment: @Caranown I would not advise using `lookup` anymore.  Instead, JavaFX (since 17) now supports [data URIs for stylesheets](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getStylesheets()).  I think that the data URIs are a better solution.   You can build a CSS stylesheet string in code to dynamically completely customize most style aspects of the chart by applying the string as a data URI, allowing more robust styling.  I think I created an example of applying this technique to apply custom chart colors, but I can't find a reference to it at the moment.

Comment: @jewelsea In my case I am setting the color dynamically for every series. As far as I can tell, data URIs would not help with this. It seems you could use data URIs to load and apply style sheets that exist as files. But I might also not understand what you had in mind.

Comment: @Caranown I'll add an example of using a data URI to style if I get time.

Answer (score 11):

**How to set a color to linecharts?**

Here's a simple way to **AreaChart** or **LineChart**

```
XYChart chart = new AreaChart();
Series series = new Series();
chart.getData().add(series);

Node fill = series.getNode().lookup(".chart-series-area-fill"); // only for AreaChart
Node line = series.getNode().lookup(".chart-series-area-line");

Color color = Color.RED; // or any other color

String rgb = String.format("%d, %d, %d",
        (int) (color.getRed() * 255),
        (int) (color.getGreen() * 255),
        (int) (color.getBlue() * 255));

fill.setStyle("-fx-fill: rgba(" + rgb + ", 0.15);");
line.setStyle("-fx-stroke: rgba(" + rgb + ", 1.0);");
```

Comment: I get a null back on these lines:

series.getNode().lookup(".chart-series-area-fill"); 
series.getNode().lookup(".chart-series-area-line");

I'm using area chart.

Comment: For a LineChart try `series.getNode().lookup(".chart-series-line");`.

Comment: I would like to emphasize that `series.getNode().lookup()` must be called **after** adding the series to chart, otherwise it returns null.

Answer (score 6):

I found a this Oracle Document on [Styling charts with CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm) and on that page scroll down to `Setting Chart Colors` for what you are specifically looking for.

**How to set a color to linecharts?**

The simplest way for this is the following CSS snippet:

```
.default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: #e9967a; }
.default-color1.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: #f0e68c; }
.default-color2.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: #dda0dd; }
```

This unfortunately will not work by id or which series, but rather the order the series are placed in the graph. You can also set the line styles though by doing:

```
.chart-series-line {    
    -fx-stroke-width: 2px;
    -fx-effect: null;
}
```

**How to set a css class to series?**

Unfortunately I do not see a way to do that. It would be nice to be able to create CSS rules based off the XYChart.Series name property, but I do not think that is possible.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about changing default colors, but I will need to disable/enable series(user will have functionality to show/hide series). And in this way it is not the best way to do it.

Comment: This solution does not change the color of the series in the legend though.

Answer (score 3):

jewelsea's answer seems to state that you have to put a style-class on every node of the series. I'm using the following code to style the series of an area chart and only assign a class to the node associated with the series.

**Example code is in Scala, but should be easy to translate.**

When creating the series, I add a series-specific style class:

```scala
 val s = new XYChart.Series[Number, Number]() //create a new series
   s.setName(seriesName)                      //set its name (display in legend)
   s.getNode.getStyleClass.add("series-" + seriesName) //add specific style class
```

Then inside the CSS file I do the following to change the fill color of the series `butterwings`:

```css
.series-butterwings *.chart-series-area-fill{
    -fx-fill: #aab597; 
}
```

This works, because the node for the series area is below the series node (which is a group in case of area chart).

Comment: I've tried doing this but found that my program hangs on the `add` call. Anybody had a similar experience? I'm doing this from ScalaFx; don't know if that makes a difference (although I'm calling the native javafx methods rather than the wrappers).

Answer (score 1):

Just did this and it worked, immediately after adding the series to the javafx LineChart

```
series.getNode().setStyle("-fx-stroke:"+color+";");
```

Answer (score 0):

To place the getNode() somewhere in the code might cause a NullPointerException, override the layoutPlotChildren() abstract method from  XYChart (AreaChart, BarChart, BubbleChart, LineChart, ScatterChart, StackedAreaChart, StackedBarChart). Minimal chart example changing line and shapes without having to use CSS style sheets:

```
public class MyChart extends LineChart {

Series s1;

public MyChart() {
    this(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
    this.getXAxis().setLabel("X");
    this.getYAxis().setLabel("Y");
}

public MyChart(Axis axis, Axis axis1) {
    super(axis, axis1);
    s1 = new XYChart.Series();
    getData().add(s1);
}

public void adddata() {
    s1.setName("Demo");
    s1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0, 1));
    s1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 2));        
    s1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 0));
    s1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 1));
}

// Override the abstract class
public void layoutPlotChildren() {
    // call super so you don't have to do all the work
    super.layoutPlotChildren();
    // not really necessary check
    if (s1 != null && s1.getNode() != null) {
        //(optional) get all the possible CSS styles you can change
        List<String> styles = s1.getNode().getStyleClass();
        //get the line from the series
        Node line = s1.getNode().lookup(".chart-series-line");
        //set some styles
        line.setStyle("-fx-stroke: black; -fx-stroke-width: 1px; -fx-effect: null; -fx-stroke-dash-array: 10 10 10 10;");
        //change the shapes
        for (Object data : s1.getData()) {
            if (data != null) {
                //only display the last data point, change the style same way as shown with the line
                if (s1.getData().indexOf(data) != s1.getData().size()-1) {
                    StackPane stackPane = (StackPane) ((XYChart.Data) data).getNode();
                    stackPane.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

And the executing code to start it:

```
public class RunJavaFX extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    MyChart chart = new MyChart();
    chart.adddata();
    Scene scene = new Scene(chart);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

}
```

[image]