# JavaFX - Why LineChart repeats colors after few plots?

Tags: java, css, colors, javafx, linechart

I try to plot 14 data sets but I have problem with colors in the LineChart. I correctly defined 14 colors in .css file like that:

```
.default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: red; } 
....
.default-color13.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: goldenrod; }
```

Everything's working fine, the lines have different colors until 7 data. Then the colors of lines are reapeted again from color0 to color7. I have no idea what is happening. Also when I don't add any .css style, linechart generated colors automatically but again it repeats colors after 7 data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java 8, the default color encoding for a series is determined by:

```
series.defaultColorStyleClass = DEFAULT_COLOR+(nextClearBit%8);
```

(That is internal implementation code from the JavaFX XYChart source).  You can see it uses a modulo 8 operation when working out style classes.  That means that any default style classes you define outside the 0 to 7 range, will just be ignored.

> Is there any other posibilities to force the LineChart to plot more colors with style class?

Yes, you don't have to use the default colors, you assign as many custom colors as you like.  For example, you can see that the following stylesheet colors specifically by series number (which is only limited by the number of series on the chart), rather than default color (which will repeat after 8 series):

```
.chart-series-line.series0 {
    -fx-stroke: green;
}
.chart-line-symbol.series0 {
    -fx-background-color: green, white;
}

.chart-series-line.series1 {
    -fx-stroke: black;
}
.chart-line-symbol.series1 {
    -fx-background-color: black, white;
}

.chart-series-line.series2 {
    -fx-stroke: crimson;
}
.chart-line-symbol.series2 {
    -fx-background-color: crimson, white;
}
```

The sample image using the above styles just shows three series, but hopefully you get the idea that it is extensible to as many series and colors as you want:

[image]

See also:

- [How to set specific color to JavaFX XYChart.Series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153370/how-to-set-specific-color-to-javafx-xychart-series)

Comment: Hmmm, OK. But is there any other posibilities to force the LineChart to plot more colors with style class? Like [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074744/core-java/styling-javafx-pie-chart-with-css.html) but it is example for Pie Chart.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now everything is perfect. Also the way to set style to every node which is presented here [How to set specific color to JavaFX XYChart.Series?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153370/how-to-set-specific-color-to-javafx-xychart-series) works fine.