# How to get the color from a series in JavaFX Chart and assign it to a checkbox

Tags: javafx, charts

I have written a sample program that generates random number of series plots using JavaFX Charts, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the color of each graph and assign it to a Checkbox that will be used to display or not display the graph. Basically I want to use the Checkboxes as a legend so that I can disable the standard legend.

Below is the complete program:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package testlinechartgraphs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestLineChartGraphs extends Application {

    final static ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> lineChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        //defining the axes
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
        Random randomNumbers = new Random();
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        //creating the chart
        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart
                = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
        lineChart.setLegendSide(Side.RIGHT);

        int randomCount = randomNumbers.nextInt(14)+1;
        //System.out.println("randomCount = " + randomCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < randomCount; i++) {
            XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
            series.setName("series_" + i);
            for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
                int x = randomNumbers.nextInt(50);

                series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(k, x));
            }
            //seriesList.add(series);
            lineChartData.add(series);
        }


        lineChart.setData(lineChartData);

//        final StackPane chartContainer = new StackPane();
//
//        Zoom zoom = new Zoom(lineChart, chartContainer);

//        chartContainer.getChildren()
//                .add(lineChart);

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        //borderPane.setCenter(chartContainer);
        borderPane.setCenter(lineChart);

        borderPane.setBottom(getLegend());
////        
        //Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 800, 600);
        //lineChart.getData().addAll(series, series1);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        //scene.getStylesheets().addAll("file:///C:/Users/siphoh/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WiresharkSeqNum/src/fancychart.css");
        //scene.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("fancychart.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.show();
    }

    public static Node getLegend() {
        HBox hBox = new HBox();

        for (final XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series : lineChartData) {
            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(series.getName());


            checkBox.setSelected(true);
            checkBox.setOnAction(event -> {
                if (lineChartData.contains(series)) {

                    lineChartData.remove(series);
                } else {
                    lineChartData.add(series);
                }
            });

            hBox.getChildren().add(checkBox);
        }

        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBox.setSpacing(20);
        hBox.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0 10 20 10");

        return hBox;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

How can I implement this in the **getLegend()**  method? any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Fred

Comment: This is tricky for some reasons ( *at least for me*), but how about if you generate some random colors, put them into *array/list*, then you set each of the line's color based on the generated colors in the array/list, so later if you want to generate checkbox based on the colors you can refer to these array/list elements.

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153370/how-to-set-specific-color-to-javafx-xychart-series) will help you.  You could define your own style sheet so you know which color matches which series.

Comment: Thanks for the response, how can I set the colors especially that the number of graphs is random, kindly give me an example still learning JavaFX.   I tried to use series.getNode.XXX, but this always gives me an NPE.  Amber, I have tried to look at those examples, but still not working for me, probably one of the reasons is that I am combining Swing and JavaFX, so am returning a JFXPanel to swing. But in the code I have given, I have simplified it to show only the JavaFX.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant by tricky, since the colors are generated randomly and you want to get the colors , but if you can somehow set the colors (like from css attribute, *-fx-stroke: #e9967a*) to each of the lines then you can generated this 6 hex digit color randomly.