# JavaFX Chart - space between legends

Tags: java, javafx

I have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ launch(args); }

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 23, 1);
    xAxis.setLabel("XX");

    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    yAxis.setLabel("YY");

    LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series1.setName("Loooooooooooooongest");
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series2.setName("Short");
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series3 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series3.setName("Loooooong");

    lineChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(lineChart));
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.centerOnScreen();

    primaryStage.show();

}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Every legend has allocated space like the longest legend.

How I can remove all that space?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a CSS Property. Maybe something like `-fx-padding` or `-fx-margin`. Not sure right now.

This could give you a good idea about for using CSS Properties in JavaFX: [How to set specific color to JavaFX XYChart.Series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153370/how-to-set-specific-color-to-javafx-xychart-series)

Also it's a great idea to use the JavaFX-SceneBuilder. You can apply CSS there and directly see what it does.

Comment: Thanks. But I figured out somehow. I hide legends from chart and create a new node with legends from chart. And there I could set everything

Comment: no, neither padding nor margin nor any other (css-) property will help, it's simply not supported - consequently, scenebuilder will not help, either ;)