# How to change color of chart?

Tags: java, javafx

How do I change bar chart color of a specific bar, and how to change every bare to same color?

```
XYChart.Series<String, Integer> exPhil = new XYChart.Series<>();
exPhil.setName("Examen philosophicum for naturvitenskap og teknologi");
exPhil.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("A", 70));
exPhil.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("B", 20));
exPhil.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("C", 40));
exPhil.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("D", 10));
exPhil.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("E", 5));
exPhil.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("F", 5));
barChart.getData().add(exPhil);
barChart.setLegendVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using CSS.

Check the oracle documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm)
and also some of the answers on stck [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11160201/5468716)

---

EDIT:
If you can't use CSS then use the class to style, you'll have to search for each of them how they are defined and use that naming, e.g.:

```
xAxis.setTickLabelFill(Color.CHOCOLATE);

yAxis.setTickLabelFill(Color.CHOCOLATE);
```

Comment: I can't use css.

Comment: @TheAlmightyBawan Why not? That is the supported mechanism.

Comment: I have not learnt how to use css. I have tried with setStyle, but i don't get it to work.