# JavaFx - Setting LineChart Series Color Programmatically

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am new to Java and so to JavaFX. I am trying to build a dynamic graph which displays live data using JavaFx LineChart.

I noticed in the oracle docs http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm#CIHGIAGE that charts can be styled using CSS.

**Is it possible to change the color of a series programmatically?**

```
public Node addLineChart(){

    //final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(-80,60,20);
    final NumberAxis yAxis;
    final CategoryAxis xAxis;

    if(firingOrderSelectionIndex >= 0){
        String selectedFiringOrder = firingOrders[cylselectionIndex][firingOrderSelectionIndex];
        String[] currentFiringOrder = selectedFiringOrder.split("-");

        xAxis = new CategoryAxis(FXCollections.observableArrayList(currentFiringOrder));            
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

        if(selectionIndex > 1){
          yAxis = new NumberAxis(-60,40,20);
        }else{
          yAxis = new NumberAxis(-75,50,15);
        }             
    }else{
        xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        yAxis = new NumberAxis(0,0,0);          
    }   

    xAxis.setLabel("Order");
    xAxis.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 14;-fx-font-weight: bolder;");
    //xAxis.setAutoRanging(false); //If you are manually setting values in the constructor you can do this.
    //otherwise if this is done, the graph will crash. So, while using constructor with no values leave this config as default.

    //xAxis.setLowerBound(1);        
    //xAxis.setUpperBound(4);
    //xAxis.setTickUnit(1);

    yAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);

    final LineChart<String,Number> lineChart = new LineChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
    lineChart.setTitle("Graph");
    lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);
    lineChart.setStyle(".default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: #f0e68c; }");

    //series.setName("Live");
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("1", 5));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2", 5));

    lineChart.getData().add(series);    
    xAxis.setVisible(false);

    return lineChart;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change line style in JavaFX 2.0 line chart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757848/how-to-dynamically-change-line-style-in-javafx-2-0-line-chart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chart.setStyle(".default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: #e9967a; }");
```

Comment: Thanks Keshan, appreciate it.

Comment: I have now added the code segment where I am doing this. But I do not see this take effect. The color of the series is still the default color. I am also taking a look at what jewelsea has suggested. It seems a little complex for a newbie. I am trying to understand the same as well.

Comment: This helped me to understand how to map precisely from the css