# JavaFX 2.2 Styling Charts

Tags: css, javafx-2, linechart

So I have my lineChart my y axis is NumberAxis and my x axis is DateAxis. I use DateAxis from lib http://myjavafx.blogspot.com/2013/09/javafx-charts-display-date-values-on.html. Thanks to Christian Schudt for that. I draw 3 lines in one series in one linechart.

I have seen few similar questions and solutions:
     [JavaFx 2.x: XYChart properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137314/javafx-2-x-xychart-properties)
     [JavaFx 2.x: XYChart properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137314/javafx-2-x-xychart-properties)
     http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm

but it wont work for me.

So I have add code:

```
lineChart.setStyle(".default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: #f0e68c, gray; }");
lineChart.setStyle(".default-color1.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: #00ff00, green; }");
lineChart.setStyle(".default-color2.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: #ff0000, red; }");
```

Please, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this with an external style sheet. Create a css file with the three strings you have passed to the setStyle(...) method, and then call

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("myFile.css").toExternalForm());
```

on the scene.

CSS has two parts to it: a rule and a selector. The rule defines the style (for example, "-fx-stroke: #f0e68c, gray;"); the selector defines to which nodes the style will be applied (for example: ".default-color0.chart-series-line": all nodes which have both the "default-color0" class and the "chart-series-line" class).

When you pass a string to a node's setStyle(...) method, you pass in only the rule, and that rule will be applied to that node. In your case, this won't work; you want to assign the style to the lines, not to the chart itself.

To use a selector you need to use an external style sheet. It is possible to achieve the same result using lineChart.lookup(...) but this is not very robust; external style sheets are far preferable.